# SQL - no output from Right Join

Tags: sql, left-join, ssms, right-join

I have one table which I select with the code: **Code A**

```
Select TDS, TL, IK
From (Select Sheet1.TOOLING_DATA_SHEET As TDS, Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL As TL, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY As IK
        From Sheet1
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE=Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL And ENT_ITEM_MASTER.USER_LAST_MODIFIED Is Not Null) As A
```

**Output:**

```
TDS                     TL          IK
TDS-1980D-10+OP10+S7    TL-000032   1
TDS-1980D-10+OP10+S7    TL-000019   34
TDS-2258-01+OP10+S4     TL-000016   53
TDS-2325PU+OP10+S1      TL-000036   7
TDS-1234-56-78          TL-000123   45
```

and another table which I select with the code: **Code B**

```
Select ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.OBJ_NAME, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY
        From ENT_LINK_OBJECTS
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY=ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.ENTITY_KEY And ENT_ITEM_MASTER.USER_LAST_MODIFIED Is Not Null) As B
```

**Output:**

```
OBJ_NAME                 ITEM_CODE   ITEM_KEY
TDS-1980D-10+OP10+S7    TL-000032      1
TDS-1980D-10+OP10+S7    TL-000019      34
TDS-2258-01+OP10+S4     TL-000032      28
TDS-2258-01+OP10+S4     TL-000016      53
TDS-2325PU+OP10+S1      TL-000036      7
TDS-2325PU+OP10+S1      TL-000009      9
```

I have Left Joined the tables in working code which gives me everything that is in Table A that is not in Table B.

I now am trying to Right Join the tables which would give me everything that is in Table B that is not in Table A. Right now the output is nothing.

---

Full code for **Right Join:**

```
Select TDS, TL, IK
From (Select Sheet1.TOOLING_DATA_SHEET, Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY
        From Sheet1
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE=Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL And ENT_ITEM_MASTER.USER_LAST_MODIFIED Is Not Null) As A
Right Join (Select ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.OBJ_NAME As TDS, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE As TL, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY As IK
        From ENT_LINK_OBJECTS
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY=ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.ENTITY_KEY And ENT_ITEM_MASTER.USER_LAST_MODIFIED Is Not Null) As B
On A.TOOLING_DATA_SHEET=B.TDS
Where A.TOOLING_DATA_SHEET is Null
```

Current output:

```
TDS    TL    IK
```

Desired output: (everything in B that is not in A)

```
TDS                       TL           IK
TDS-2258-01+OP10+S4     TL-000032      28
TDS-2325PU+OP10+S1      TL-000009      9
```

I can add my working code for my Left Join if that is helpful. I have also tried switching the Select areas, doing a Left Join, and changing the Null statement to attempt a Left Join, which provides no output as well.

**EDIT:**

How my code works with a Left Join:

```
Select TDS, TL, IK
From (Select Sheet1.TOOLING_DATA_SHEET As TDS, Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL As TL, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY As IK
        From Sheet1
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE=Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL And ENT_ITEM_MASTER.USER_LAST_MODIFIED Is Not Null) As A
Left Join (Select ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.OBJ_NAME, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY
        From ENT_LINK_OBJECTS
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY=ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.ENTITY_KEY And ENT_ITEM_MASTER.USER_LAST_MODIFIED Is Not Null) As B
On A.TDS=B.OBJ_NAME
Where B.OBJ_NAME is Null
```

**OUTPUT:** (everything in A that is not in B)

```
TDS                  TL        IK
TDS-1234-56-78     TL-000123   45
```

Comment: TDS, TL and IK are the column names from the blank side of the join which will be null.  You need to pull in OBJ_Name, Item_COde, and Item_Key instead.  eg.  `SELECT OBJ_NAME, ITEM_CODE, ITEM_KEY` instead of `Select TDS,TL,IK`  If I'm right, you're current output may show blank, but it shows 2 blank rows!

Comment: That seemed like a brilliant solution and I think ultimately that will help me out a lot, thank you. Unfortunately, the output is still nothing @xQbert . I have altered my code in the question if you could check and make sure I executed what you had in mind

Comment: It's because @tirma is right the join criteria is insufficient.  because TDS and obj_name match  all records including 28 and 29 are removed.  You need to add `AND A.TL=B.Item_Code and A.IK = B.Item_key` to the right join criteria

Comment: I don't know why I wouldn't have needed that in my working Left Join then though. Where would I add those? I am trying to add those in my `on` statement after the `right join` but obviously B isn't defined yet so I do not know where to put it @xQbert

Comment: You would need them in the left join if you had data (or lack there of) which would cause similar issues.  Simply put you MUST join on the data which make the records UNIQUE or you will get extra records you likely will not want, or in this case, remove records you do not want to.  TDS alone isn't unique. TDS with TL might be but TDS with TL and IK ARE unique based on data presented.

Comment: see answer below for how I would write using right join.

Comment: What I'm saying though is that i have a Left Join that is working correctly. Therefore, I do not know why a Right Join would not. I haved added the code for my working Left Join above if that is of any use @xQbert

Comment: the reason your left join works is because you don't have data which would cause it not to work in your examples...   add `TDS-1234-56-78          TL-000124   46` to table A and `TDS-1234-56-78          TL-000123   45` to table B and your left join will stop working correctly.  Put another way your left joins working because you luckily don't have data which would give you improper results! Normally the left and right join criteria WOULD be the same.  you just didn't HAVE to have it the same due to your data this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---You have two problems

1. Since you want all records from B not in A.  You need to display B table Columns
2. Your Join criteria doesn't quantify unique records.  28 and 9 are being removed because TDS-2258-01+OP10+S4 and TDS-2325PU+OP10+S1 do exist in table A.  The issue is TDS-2258-01+OP10+S4     TL-000032 doesn't exist in A nor does TDS-2325PU+OP10+S1      TL-000009.  The criteria you're using to JOIN on is incorrect.  To know the CORRECT values ***you*** need to specify the relationship between the tables or simply  (based on displayed data) use `On A.TDS=B.OBJ_NAME
   and A.TL = B.Item_Code
   and A.IK = B.Item_key`

Meaning final result would be:

```
Select B.TDS, B.TL, B.IK
From (Select Sheet1.TOOLING_DATA_SHEET, Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY
        From Sheet1
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE=Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL And ENT_ITEM_MASTER.USER_LAST_MODIFIED Is Not Null) As A
Right Join (Select ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.OBJ_NAME As TDS, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE As TL, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY As IK
        From ENT_LINK_OBJECTS
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY=ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.ENTITY_KEY And ENT_ITEM_MASTER.USER_LAST_MODIFIED Is Not Null) As B
On A.TDS=B.OBJ_NAME
and A.TL = B.Item_Code
and A.IK = B.Item_ke
Where A.TOOLING_DATA_SHEET is Null
```

If you're RDBMS supports MINUS (EXCEPT for SQL SERVER) this would also work

```
(SELECT ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.OBJ_NAME As TDS, 
   ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE As TL, 
   ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY As IK
 FROM ENT_LINK_OBJECTS
 INNER JOIN ENT_ITEM_MASTER
   ON ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY=ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.ENTITY_KEY 
  AND ENT_ITEM_MASTER.USER_LAST_MODIFIED Is Not Null) As B
EXCEPT 
(SELECT Sheet1.TOOLING_DATA_SHEET, 
        Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL, 
        ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY
 FROM Sheet1
 INNER JOIN ENT_ITEM_MASTER
   ON ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE=Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL 
  AND ENT_ITEM_MASTER.USER_LAST_MODIFIED Is Not Null)  A
```

It basically says take result set B and subtract from it Result Set A. which leaves you with.... the two records you're after..  This only works if all columns match.  Outer joins or exists/not exists provide greater flexibility.

[Visual Aid](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) on Joins to help better understand

Comment: I stand behind this answer I find no fault between the added join criteria and use of correct column names.

Comment: I personally don't see anything wrong with this answer. I do think you need "EXCEPT" rather than minus as I believe the op is in SQL Server and I don't think MINUS works there, I think EXCEPT is the alternative.

Answer (score 2):

From what you are describing in comments you are looking for a Not Exists rather than a Right Join.
A right join will give you everything in table B plus everything that matches in table A.

Not exists will find everything in Table B that is not in Table A. You need something like the below:

```
Select ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.OBJ_NAME, e1.ITEM_CODE, e1.ITEM_KEY
        From ENT_LINK_OBJECTS
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER e1
        On e1.ITEM_KEY=ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.ENTITY_KEY And e1.USER_LAST_MODIFIED Is Not Null
        Where not exists
        (Select *
        From Sheet1
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE=Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL And ENT_ITEM_MASTER.USER_LAST_MODIFIED Is Not Null
        where ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY = e1.ITEM_KEY)
```

Comment: Right join works here.  due to the where clause only returning records which are NULL in A.  The problem is two fold 1, the columns returned are from wrong table and 2, the join criteria is insufficient to quantify a unique record. 28 and 9 are being removed because  TDS-2258-01+OP10+S4 and TDS-2325PU+OP10+S1  do exist in table A.

Comment: Yes good point Right Join would work when I think about it. However not exists seems like a better solution to me personally.

Comment: Depending on engine, keys, indexes... it may be faster but both work effectively.  Minus should be fastest, followed by not exists, followed by right join but only marginally faster

Comment: Yes it is very dependent on those factors and I suppose it's also down to personal preference and what's easiest to read for the developer

Comment: This seems like a great solution. And yes my Right Join would work because it is not a full right join, it sets A to be Null. I was trying to do a Right Join (with Nulls) because I already have a working Left Join (with nulls) and was hoping to write similar code for everyone who uses it easily understand. I tried your solution and I get the error: conversaion failed when converting the varchar value 'TL-000212' to data type int. TL-000212 is not present in the sheets I am trying to work with so I do not know whre this error is coming from. Ideas? @ChristianBarron

Comment: @user4888 try the updated that should hopefully rid you of the error

Comment: @ChristianBarron hm, seems like great code but still the output is nothing. I am stumped as to why that would not work... Any ideas?

Comment: @ChristianBarron I have also edited my question to include my working Left Join (with Nulls) in case that is helpful at all

Comment: @user4888 Yes it was confused due to field name. The updated should work, let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems easy. You told us:IT would give me everything that is in Table B that is not in Table A

But in the expected result, you told us   TDS-2258-01+OP10+S4   must be in the output, and this row is ont the Table A, so it will not be in the output.

I think you wanted to make the join by the field ITEM_KEY and IK instead of using A.TDS=B.OBJ_NAME

Also in the output you should show OBJ_NAME, ITEM_CODE and ITEM_KEY  instead of TDS,TL,IK

This is the final query:

```
Select OBJ_NAME, ITEM_CODE, ITEM_KEY
From (Select Sheet1.TOOLING_DATA_SHEET As TDS, Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL As TL, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY As IK
        From Sheet1
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE=Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL And ENT_ITEM_MASTER.USER_LAST_MODIFIED Is Not Null) As A
Right Join (Select ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.OBJ_NAME, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY
        From ENT_LINK_OBJECTS
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY=ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.ENTITY_KEY And ENT_ITEM_MASTER.USER_LAST_MODIFIED Is Not Null) As B
On A.IK=B.ITEM_KEY
Where A.TDS is Null
```

Comment: No because with right join, as far as I am understanding, you set everything in Table A to be NULL. Thus everything that overlaps between A and B, and everything in A is removed. A has item keys : 1, 34, 53, 7 and 45. B has item keys: 1, 34, 28, 53, 7, and 9. Everything in A is removed, and everything that overlaps. So from B: 1, 34, and 7 are removed, leaving 28 and 9. Correct?

Comment: @user4888 your understanding of right joins is incorrect. You're after something completely different

Comment: `IK = Item_Code`?!? `IK = 1` `Item_Code = TL-000032` not sure how those two will ever equal.

Comment: @ChristianBarron I am learning Right Joins from what I find in Google and here basically so it may be completely wrong. However, I do the same with a Left Join which, what I've learned so far is incredibly similar, to get everything that is in Table A that is not in Table B and it works correctly. My frustration lies there with not understanding how I could not simply flip the two with ease. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Tirma , IK is ITEM_KEY. ITEM_KEY and ITEM_CODE would not be equal to each other

Comment: sorry @user4888   i make a mistake. Please test the query as i say.